# Assembly, operation suffix not clicking for me

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm not a student, but I am using a textbook called "Computer Systems, a Programmer's Perspective" to learn about processor architecture and assembly.  I'm just getting into the section about IA32 assembly, and it asks this question:

For each of the following lines of assembly language, determine the appropriate instruction suffix based on the operands. (For example, mov can be rewritten as movb, movw, or movl.)

```
mov %eax, (%esp)
mov (%eax), %dx
mov $0xFF, %bl
mov (%esp,%edx,4), %dh
push $0xFF
mov %dx, (%eax)
pop %edi
```

I've looked at the answer key, and some of them make sense, like `push $0xFF` since that is a const the size of a byte.  Like I said, I don't need to know the answers, as those are provided in the answer key, but the *reasons* aren't in the answer key.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mov %eax, (%esp)
```

Double word cause 32-bit value of whole register `%eax` are moving.

```
mov (%eax), %dx
```

Word cause 16-bit value are moving into the half of the `%edx` register.,

```
mov $0xFF, %bl
```

Byte. Obviously.

```
mov (%esp,%edx,4), %dh
```

Byte. At the left side we have an address, but at the right side we have 8-bit quarter of the `%edx` register.

```
push $0xFF
```

It depends. 80386 has the instruction 6A that pushes 8-bit constant to the stack. But how Michael Petch said in comments, it depends on the stack address size.

```
mov %dx, (%eax)
```

Word. 16-bit `%dx` are moving into somewhere.

```
pop %edi
```

Double word. 32-bit register `%edi`.

Now, 8-bit values matches with the suffix **b** (byte), 16-bit values matches with the suffix **w** (word), and 32-bit values matches with the suffix **l** (double or *long* word).

**UPDATE**

4 registers (A, B, C, and D) are available in parts.
Whole 32-bit registers are E**A**X, E**B**X, and so on.
Low 16-bit halves of the registers are **A**X, **B**X, and so on.
High 8-bit of low 16-bit quarters are **A**H, **B**H (where H means *high*).
Low 8-bit of low 16-bit quarters are **A**L, **B**L (where L means *low*).

Comment: Ah, I see.  I didn't realize what things like %dx and %bl were representing.  Those are portions of registers.  This makes sense.  Thank you very much!

Comment: `Byte. Obviously.` you sure? It depends on the stack address size. If this is 32-bit code on Linux then you can't push a byte. The smallest value you can push is a 16-bit word. So `push $0xff` actually is a `pushw $0xff` .

Comment: Actually, for the stack push the textbook does show `pushl 0xFF`

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks. I'll update the answer, and I should correct my own knowledge.

Comment: @Borromakot, Thanks. I updated the answer with this info.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko More than anything, thank you for the great answer.  I hope someone else will find this list of examples useful!

Comment: Yeah, actually is a long (it is 1am so the brain isn't working on all cylinders). However it should also be possible to push a word as well. `w` and `l` would be the only possible ones that would work. A byte will be sign extended into the wider size. `pushw $0xff` would push a 2 byte word on the stack as `$0xffff`. `pushl $0xff`would push the 4 byte long onto the stack as `$0xffffffff`

Answer (score 0):

The instruction suffix can infered by the operand types.

For example in the first line one operand is EAX, which immediately shows that it would need an `l` instruction.
Conversly `mov (%esp,%edx,4), %dh` has an operand size of bytes, so it would need a `b` suffix.

BTW: `push $0xFF` with a byte operand is usually a bad idea because the stack gets missaligned. I was once searching a bug because of something like that, where Windows always gave me strange error message (Permission denied) on the `CreateFile` function, because of a missaligned filename and it was quite hard to spot. :) Other operating systems may have similar restrictions.

Comment: Thank you for the information!  I'm going to accept Mark's answer because I believe the format will be very good for others looking for an answer to this question.  Thank you for your help.